# MySQL sort by column, then sort within that set

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

| price | date | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 20:00 | 1 |
| 3000 | 23:00 | 2 |
| 5000 | 21:00 | 2 |
| 2000 | 19:00 | 1 |

How can I sort by **date** AND **product_id** where **product_id** is the primary sort? So it ends up looking like:

| price | date | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 19:00 | 1 |
| 1000 | 20:00 | 1 |
| 5000 | 21:00 | 2 |
| 3000 | 23:00 | 2 |

I tried

```sql
SELECT * FROM prices ORDER BY date, product_id
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT * FROM prices
 ORDER BY product_id
) AS p ORDER BY date
```

But that didn't return what I wanted

Comment: Did you try `ORDER BY product_id, date` ?

Comment: Oh oops that was too obvious, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So you want the ordering by products, but based on the earliest date of the product.

Happily, you can use window functions in the `order by`:

```
select p.*
from prices p
order by min(date) over (partition by product),
         product,
         date;
```

The `order by` keys do the following:

1. Calculate the minimum date of a product and use that as the first overall sort key.
2. Order by product, so if there are ties for the minimum date, the products are separated.
3. Order by the date within each product